# Is there any way to pause the Java program without using threads?

Tags: java, netbeans

Is there any way to pause the Java program  without using thread? I want to know another way to pause the program without exit program like we use `System.exit` to exit the system. Is there any way to pause,stuck the program the same as System.exit does.

Comment: you can busy wait, something like while(true){}

Comment: Do you have a reason for not wanting to use Thread.sleep()?

Comment: What did you tried? Please put the code in your question!

Answer (score 0):

When you say pause, it means you want some code lines X to execute first and then code lines Y.

Between X and Y, you want pause which could be via thread sleep and wait. Wait would mean notify from another thread. But you don't want to use threads.

Another way would be external trigger via property, whose value would act as a condition in your loop. The loop will be infinite on initial value of property, and condition will be false the moment you change it.

Another way to solve is let first X lines execute and Y would be inside MVC controller, which would be again external trigger via service call. This is possible if it's a web application.

Comment: thx buddy...i got it..this is not a web application.i used many more things but not threads.but finally i had to use threads..  :)